# How to tell QPluginLoader to check for dll dependencies in containing folder instead of exe folder

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake

I have a dll which is some kind of plugin and I intend to deploy it as a package, the dll and all it's dependencies (also dlls) in one package. The issue that I have is that the dll is checking for it's dependencies in the exe folder instead of its own folder, its dependencies are next to it.

Is there a way to tell it where the dependencies are?

Edit:
In my case the plugin is loaded by QPluginLoader and the answers hinted that this is relevant as the loader decides where to look for dependencies.

Comment: Your OS looks for the dependencies using this method: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications

Comment: You probably want to load the plugin with `LoadLibraryEx` with an absolute path and with `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alex Reinking pointed out the loader is responsible for finding the dlls, in my case the loading was done by QPluginLoader and a solution was to set the current directory to the plugin directory as the loader looks in the current directory for dlls:

```
QDir pluginsDir(QLatin1String("../src/"));
QDir::setCurrent(pluginsDir.path());
QPluginLoader pluginLoader(pluginsDir.absoluteFilePath(fileName));
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order):

> Note that the standard search strategy and the alternate search strategy specified by `LoadLibraryEx` with `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` differ in just one way: The standard search begins in the calling application's directory, and the alternate search begins in the directory of the executable module that `LoadLibraryEx` is loading.

This is exactly the behavior you described. You cannot change this behavior from the build system (in re: the [cmake] tag), but will need to modify the application's plugin-loading logic.